# putting get chrome storage local value to a dict

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to get a local storage value outside the call, to use it in another function,
I see this is an async function and outside log gets called first, but cant rly wrap how it works and why I get the value on the second call, but not it the first call.
So the question is how do I get the value outside the call and make First Call work as second call ?

```
var Credentials = []
chrome.storage.local.get(["Key"], function(result) {
  const o = result.Key.email
  console.log("this is email", result.key.email)
  Credentials.push({"email": result.key.email})
  console.log("Second Call",Credentials[0].email)
});
console.log("First Call",Credentials[0])
```

Comment: What makes you think it should be called second?

Comment: that is what consol shows

Comment: Sorry. You said _"make First Call work as second call"_. What makes you think it _should_ be called second as it currently is? --- If you do want it called second, call it after `console.log("Second Call"...`

Comment: what I want is to get the Credentials outside the function, to use it elsewhere

Comment: Please read the question I linked to and also this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I use https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill you can use a Promise. To prevent a callback hell....